# Search on a binary tree

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp, lookup

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html):

> Exercise 2.66.  Implement the lookup
>   procedure for the case where the set
>   of records is structured as a binary
>   tree, ordered by the numerical values
>   of the keys.

I wrote the following:

```
(define key car)
(define make-record cons)
(define value cadar)

(define (lookup given-key set-of-records)
  (cond ((null? set-of-records) false)
        ((equal? given-key (key (car set-of-records)))
         (car set-of-records))
        ((< given-key (key (car set-of-records))) (lookup given-key (left-branch set-of-records)))
        (else (lookup given-key (right-branch set-of-records)))))
```

(The following part is from the book)

```
(define (entry tree) (car tree))
(define (left-branch tree) (cadr tree))
(define (right-branch tree) (caddr tree))
(define (make-tree entry left right)
  (list entry left right))

(define (list->tree elements)
  (car (partial-tree elements (length elements))))

(define (partial-tree elts n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (cons '() elts)
      (let ((left-size (quotient (- n 1) 2)))
        (let ((left-result (partial-tree elts left-size)))
          (let ((left-tree (car left-result))
                (non-left-elts (cdr left-result))
                (right-size (- n (+ left-size 1))))
            (let ((this-entry (car non-left-elts))
                  (right-result (partial-tree (cdr non-left-elts)
                                              right-size)))
              (let ((right-tree (car right-result))
                    (remaining-elts (cdr right-result)))
                (cons (make-tree this-entry left-tree right-tree)
                      remaining-elts))))))))
```

How can my answer be improved?